# ssl\tls public key vs ethereum blockchain public key

Tags: tls, certificates, blockchain, ethereum

In a ssl/tls, the public key for a domain is included in the ssl/tls certificate that your computer downloaded and stored locally.

In the ethereum blockchain ecosystem, the public key is derived from the message signature since there is no centralized storage location.

Are the above understanding of two ecosystems correct?

Comment: This is quite easy to look up. It took me less than 5 minutes to get verification. Is this what you really wanted to ask? Or is there more context here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks research effort, unless there. is more to the question that is not disclosed.